# How do I select my CSS module class using document.querySelector?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I want to be able to select **`styles.scrollValue`** using the `document.querySelector()`

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./Navbar.module.scss";

const Navbar = () => {
  const handleScroll = () => {
    document.querySelector(styles.scrollValue).innerHTML = scrollY;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  });
  return (
    <nav className={styles.navbar}>
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <h1 className={styles.scrollValue}>0</h1>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Running this code I get an error:

> TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null

I know I can add a global class to that element doing this:

```
className={`${styles.scrollValue} scrollValue`}
```

But that would ruin the advantage of using CSS Modules.

Is there a way to select the CSS Module class without adding another one to it?

Comment: Whats inside of `./Navbar.module.scss` (and what is contained in `styles.scrollValue` by that definition)? It _should_ be a css selector. Please add the **relevant** contents of `./Navbar.module.scss` to your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to select it as a class,

```
document.querySelector(`.${styles.scrollValue}`)
```

Calling `styles.property` returns a value such as the following,

`scrollValue: '_src_styles_module__scrollValue'`

So when you call document.querySelector it's looking for `_src_styles_module__scrollValue` which has no selector type such `.`, or `#` which makes it look for an element that would match `<_src_styles_module__scrollValue>` (in this case). Since there is no element with that name or the hashed name it will return null.

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sun-flfpj?file=/src/App.js)**