# How to grab a DOM element in Next.js when class name is randomized

Tags: css, sass, next.js, css-modules

I'm building a Next.js app (v 12.1.0) and in my Nav component, I'm trying to grab a DOM element with

```
const nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
```

This returns an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
```

because this element gets rendered as

```
<div class="Nav_nav___cOea"></div>
```

instead of the .nav class that I use in my CSS.

I'm using css modules and sass, so my CSS is in Nav.module.sass (which loads just fine), however, as you see above, it gets rendered with a different class name. How do I grab the rendered element? Or how do I stop next.js from randomizing class names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to refer to the class in the querySelector like so:

```
const nav = document.querySelector(`.${styles.nav}`);
```

This assumes that styles were imported like so:

```
import styles from '../styles/Nav.module.sass';
```

This is based on the accepted response to this question:
[How do I select my CSS module class using document.querySelector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69617831/how-do-i-select-my-css-module-class-using-document-queryselector)